# Entity framework. Include one-2-one entity explicitly

Tags: entity-framework

I have one-2-one relation:

```
public class Branch
{
    public Branch()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        AddressInfo = new AddressInfo(this);
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressInfo AddressInfo { get; set; }
}

public class AddressInfo
{
    private AddressInfo() {}
    public AddressInfo(Branch b)
    {
        Branch = b;
        BId = bank.Id;
    }
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public string XXX { get; set; }
}
```

in mapping:

```
HasRequired(x => x.AddressInfo)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Branch);
```

Simple

```
from b in dc.Branches
select new { b.Id, b.AddressInfo.XXX };
```

works, but I want AddressInfo to be loaded in such query

```
var dtos = (from b in dc.Branches
    select new { b /*, b.AddressInfo*/ }).ToList();
```

If uncomment `, b.AddressInfo`, there is `Multiplicity constraint violated. The role '…' of the relationship '…' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1` error.

Comment: if you give both your table the 1..1 multiplicity, it'll be hard to create two object in the exact same time and make them see themselve without having a little 0.0001 seconde of key violation, i recomend you to have a 1..0 multiplicity somewhere so you can create your objects in a certain order

Comment: `The entity types 'AddressInfo' and 'Branch' cannot share table 'Table' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.`